# Part limit in Complex Analysis

Tags: analysis

Can somebody explain to me why this limit:

$lim(n(\sqrt[n]{r} - 1))$ converges to $logr$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Thanks a lot!

This was a part of a limit in Complex Analysis asking to show that

$n(\sqrt[n]z -1) \rightarrow logz$

Comment: Where r is the |z|

Answer (score 0):

We have by l'Hospital 
$$ \lim_n n \bigl(\sqrt[n]r - 1\bigr) = \lim_n\frac{e^{(\log r)/n} - 1}{1/n}
= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{x\log r} - 1}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\log r \cdot e^{x\log r}}{1} = \log r  
$$

Comment: Note that replacing the limit over $\mathbb N$ by a limit over $\mathbb R$ is fine, as both numerator and denominator are monotone. Dropping the $-1$ makes l'Hopital not appliciable, as then the numerator goes to $1$ giving limit $\infty$ (as it should be) instead of "$\frac 00$".